# Lombok @Synchronized with Mockito throws NPE

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, synchronized, lombok

Given `synchronized` and Lombok's `@Synchronized`, the latter causes a `NullPointerException` when mocking a method under test. Given

```
public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        // Expensive initialization,
        // so use Mock, not Spy
    }

    public synchronized String a()
    {
        return "a";
    }

    @Synchronized // <-- Causes NPE during tests, literally, here
    public String b()
    {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

and the Jupiter test class

```
class ProblemTest
{
    @Mock
    private Problem subject;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup()
    {
        initMocks(this);
        // There is more mocking. Please don't let the simplicity
        // of this example throw you off.
        doCallRealMethod().when( subject ).a();
        doCallRealMethod().when( subject ).b();

        // This is a hack, but works. Can we rely on this?
        // ReflectionTestUtils.setField( subject, "$lock", new Object[0] );
    }

    @Test
    void a()
    {
        // Succeeds
        assertEquals( "a", subject.a() );
    }

    @Test
    void b()
    {
        // NullPointerException during tests
        assertEquals( "b", subject.b() );
    }
}
```

Lombok adds something like the following:

```
private final Object $lock = new Object[0]; // We can't rely on this name
...
public String b()
{
    synchronized($lock)
    {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

How to mock a method that is decorated with Lombok's *default* `@Synchronized` annotation?

---

Here is the stack trace, though it is unhelpful. I suspect Lombok adds a field as in my example above, and of course that is not injected into the mock, so voilà, NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ericdraken.Problem.b(Problem.java:16) // <-- @Synchronized keyword
    at com.ericdraken.ProblemTest.b(ProblemTest.java:43) // <-- assertEquals( "b", subject.b() );
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ... [snip] ...
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Please show the exception stack trace.

Comment: It will not help you as it NPEs at the @Synchronized keyword, but I can add it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with Lombok, the following also fails.

```
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
public class ProblemTest {
    @Mock
    private Problem subject;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup()
    {
        doCallRealMethod().when( subject ).c();

    }

    @Test
    void c()
    {
        // NullPointerException during tests
        assertEquals( "c", subject.c() );
    }
}

class Problem
{
  private final Map<String,String> c = new HashMap<>(){{put("c","c");}};

    public String c(){
        return c.get("c");
    }
}
```

To be precise, you are not really mocking `Problem`, you are **partially mocking** via `doCallRealMethod` hence the issue.

This is also called out in Mockito's [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod--),

> Mockito.spy() is a recommended way of creating partial mocks. The reason is it guarantees real methods are called against correctly constructed object because you're responsible for constructing the object passed to spy() method.

`doCallRealMethod()` is called on a mock which is not guaranteed to have the object created the way it's supposed to be.

So to answer your question, yes that's the way you create a mock, but `doCallRealMethod` is always a gamble irrespective of Lombok.

You can use `spy` if you really want to call the actual method.

```
  @Test
  void c() {
    Problem spyProblem = Mockito.spy(new Problem());
    assertEquals("c", spyProblem.c());
    verify(spyProblem, Mockito.times(1)).c();
  }
```

Comment: With respect, this is an issue with Lombok. My logic outlined in my question is accurate and on point. In fact, if you look at my "hack" comment, you will realize as I did that `ReflectionTestUtils.setField( subject, "$lock", new Object() );` will solve the problem, but this cannot be relied on. Thank you for your suggestion nonetheless. Additionally, Spy is not what I want here. I've intentionally made the problem minimal and viable, so let's stick with Mock, kindly.

Comment: How is it an issue with Lombok? Look at my test case the method I put in my test has nothing to do with Lombok and it still fails with NPE, any member variable which needs to be initialized is not in `doCallRealMethod`. You would need to use the ReflectionTestUtils to initialize. Also why do you want to use a mock and do a doCallRealMethod, seems unusual.

Comment: Because Lombok is using a hidden field we have no control over so it is a Lombok issue. Seems straightforward. Spy creates an actual object instance. Mock does not. That should suffice. That’s alright if you can’t solve this test situation as it is. Maybe there is no solution other to initialize a $lock field and hope that doesn’t change over the years. This question is about Mock. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, let's  say class Problem was in a library. You still would not have control over it's private members. I saying this problem is not something specific to Lombok, it is the same for any **private** field of the class.

Comment: I'm sorry you are not getting it. This is not a question about the universe. Your solution doesn't solve the problem for a mock with Lombok. I've put in the time to go through the Lombok source code and even the config, and unlike your answer, I've reached a solution that works with Mock. I'll be more clear: I do not want Spy. I cannot use Spy. I do not want all the fields set or constructor invoked. All I want is @Synchronized and it's hidden lock. Since I've put in the effort to go through the source, I know what field to inject now, and now knowing that, this problem about Lombok is solved.

Comment: @Drakes Then consider this answer, and mine, to be frame challenges. In my opinion you are attempting to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Douglas The problem of a hidden field being added has been solved to my satisfaction already. Thanks for your feedback nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

#### Synopsis

Project Lombok has the `@Synchronized` annotation on methods to hide the underlying and auto-generated private lock(s), whereas `synchronized` locks on `this`.

When using a Mockito mock (not a spy, because there are situations when we don't want a full object instantiated), fields are not initialized. That means as well the auto-generated "lock" field is null which causes the NPE.

#### Solution 1 - Field injection

Looking at Lombok [source code](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/72f546f9cb424932024e91b2c4431aea51909c42/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleSynchronized.java), we see that Lombok uses the following lock names:

```
private static final String INSTANCE_LOCK_NAME = "$lock";
private static final String STATIC_LOCK_NAME = "$LOCK";
```

Unless Lombok suddenly changes this in the future, this means we can do field injection even if it feels like a "hack":

```
@BeforeEach
void setup()
{
    initMocks(this);
    ...
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField( subject, "$lock", new Object[0] );
}
```

#### Solution 2 - Declare a lock, then field injection

The question asks about `@Synchronized`, not `@Synchronized("someLockName")`, but if you can explicitly declare the lock name, then you can use solution one with confidence about the lock field name.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that you are combining calling the real method with a mock rather than a spy. This is dangerous *in general*, as whether it works for anything depends very much on the internal implementation of the method in question.

Lombok only matters because it works by altering that internal implementation during compilation, in a way that happens to require proper object initialization to work where the original method does not.

If you're going to configure a mock to call the real method, you should probably use a spy instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It’s only dangerous when the developer doesn’t know the difference between mock and spy, I agree. Please see the above comments in the other answer. Spy is not a panacea. It shouldn’t matter for this question, but I don’t want the object instantiated. You must consider what heavy operations could take place during instantiation. So this problem is about Mock, Lombok, and the hidden lock field it creates. Thanks the suggestion though.

Comment: @Drakes If heavy operations are happening as part of object instantiation, that's another, separate, problem of its own. The fact that you have that problem is a reason to prefer avoiding a spy, but that does not change what the appropriate solution to `doCallRealMethod` throwing is. I would recommend a) changing the class to do the expensive operation(s) outside of the constructor (which I would recommend regardless), and b) then using a spy.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas. One word: SpringBoot. This problem has been solved to my satisfaction already. Thanks for your feedback nonetheless.

Comment: @Drakes How does SpringBoot contribute to this problem? You're mocking a class that you defined yourself, not one from a framework or library.

Comment: This was a minimal viable problem. I think we're done with this question.

Comment: @Drakes Minimum viable for the solution you appear to have already decided on before asking. I am not convinced that you are solving the correct problem. Or as Meta Stack Exchange puts it, I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.